# CSS Grid elements overflow container off the page vertically only

Tags: css, css-grid

My page here is working in every way except one. If the height of the screen or browser window is very small compared to the width, the images do not resize, overflow their containers, and the buttons are pushed down offscreen. When the page is resized horizontally, it works correctly, with the images resizing. I have tried the commonly-suggested `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));` - but while that does prevent the buttons from being pushed offscreen, the images end up in an overlapping pile in the center of the screen instead.

[image: example of overlapping images]

```css
/* ----Body & Background---- */
html {
  --green: #78C043;
  --blue: #42C8F4;
  --purple: #AA6DA3;
  --grey: #544D56;
}

body {
  background: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: var(--green);
}

#backGrid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 2vw;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 96vw;
  background-image: url(http://fatcat-designs.com/images/green-grid2.svg);
  background-size: 40px;
  border-color: rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.01rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75) inset;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  z-index: -10;
}

#particleWeb {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* ---Grid---- */
.grid-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2.5vh;
  left: 2.5vw;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 95vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

/* ----Logos---- */
#logo {
  width: 80%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#Farrago {
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

#deptLogo {
  width: 75%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#NSCS {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

/* ----Button ----*/
#enter {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}

/* ----All Buttons---- */
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.5);
  border-color: var(--green);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5);
  color: var(--blue);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 150ms ease;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
}

button::-moz-selection {
  background: var(--blue);
  color: #000000;
}

button::selection {
  background: var(--blue);
  color: #000000;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.25);
  border-color: var(--blue);
}

button:focus {
  color: var(--blue);
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--blue);
}

button:active {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0);
  color: var(--purple);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5) inset;
}

/* ----Specific Buttons---- */
.enter {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Farrago Fiction Narrative Stability Customer Support</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Montserrat+Subrayada:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"> 
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="backGrid">
    <div id="particleWeb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container" id="glitchArea">
    <div id="logo">
        <img id="Farrago" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/FarragoFuture_Logo.png" alt="Farrago Fiction logo" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    <div id="deptLogo">
        <img id="NSCS" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/Narrative_Stability_Customer_Support_Centered.png" alt="Narrative Stability Customer Support" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div id="enter">
        <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="location.href='/dead_messages/userSite.php';">User Site</a></button>
        <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="location.href='/dead_messages/loginPage.php';">Employee Login</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>     

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I went ahead and dumped the whole thing into the snippet there, minus some javascript that wasn't relevant to the formatting. Resize it to make the screen wide but short and you'll see the problem. How can I fix this?

I also have it in a CodePen if that's easier to look at: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/keskaowl/pen/GRjNemJ?editors=1000)

Comment: is [this](https://prnt.sc/xbbw9m) the result you're looking for? Isn't it better with overflow?

Comment: Yes, that's the result I'm looking for. What needs to change?

Comment: @karmicRetribution does my answer help you?

Comment: @karmicRetribution the changes i made were basically what Nimitt did, take a look at his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming to a slightly different solution in the end; I started with what @Nimitt changed above, but the images were frustratingly stubborn about being able to resize for both orientations.

I found a great article on dynamic sizing in CSS here: [https://ishadeed.com/article/min-max-css](https://ishadeed.com/article/min-max-css/) and the tips there about using the dimensional ratio of images to allow them to resize correctly with the viewport.

Here's the end result. There is probably a better, cleaner/more efficient solution out there somewhere, so don't hesitate to add more answers for the next person who comes along!

```css
/* ----Body & Background---- */
html {
  --green: #78C043;
  --blue: #42C8F4;
  --purple: #AA6DA3;
  --grey: #544D56;
}

body {
  background: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: var(--green);
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 2vw;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 96vw;
  background-image: url(http://fatcat-designs.com/images/green-grid2.svg);
  background-size: 40px;
  border-color: rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.01rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75) inset;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  z-index: -10;
}

#particleWeb { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
} 

/* ---Grid---- */
.grid-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5vh;
    left: 2.5vw;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 95vh;
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}

/* ----Logos---- */
#logo {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
}

#Farrago {
  --ratio: 704 / 1819;
  --container-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  width: calc(150vw * var(--ratio));
  max-width: calc(var(--container-height) * var(--ratio) * 1.25);
  height: 100%;
  max-height: var(--container-height);
}

#deptLogo {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
}

#NSCS  {
  --ratio:  968 / 1657;
  --container-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100vw * var(--ratio));
  max-width: calc(var(--container-height) * var(--ratio) * 0.75);
  height: 100%;
  max-height: var(--container-height);
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* ----Button ----*/
#enter {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* ----All Buttons---- */
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.5);
  border-color: var(--green);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5);
  color: var(--blue);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
}
button::selection {
  background: var(--blue); 
  color: #000000;
}
button::-moz-selection {
  background: var(--blue); 
  color: #000000;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.25);
  border-color: var(--blue);
}
button:focus {
  color: var(--blue);
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--blue);
}
button:active {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0);
  color: var(--purple);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5) inset;
}

/* ----Specific Buttons---- */
.enter {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: min(3vw, 3vh);
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    max-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="particleWeb"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container" id="glitchArea">
  <div id="logo">
      <img id="Farrago" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/FarragoFuture_Logo.png" alt="Farrago Fiction logo">
  </div>
  <div id="deptLogo">
      <img id="NSCS" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/Narrative_Stability_Customer_Support_Centered.png" alt="Narrative Stability Customer Support">
  </div>
  <div id="enter">
    <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="location.href='/dead_messages/userSite.php';">User Site</button>
    <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="location.href='/dead_messages/loginPage.php';">Employee Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. I have made the width and height of main containers `#logo`, `#deptLogo` and `#enter` dynamic. Also, I have made `font-size` and `padding` for buttons dynamic.

See the Snippet below:

```js
// Glitch Effects //

function addGlitch() {
  var gltch = document.getElementById('glitchArea');
  gltch.classList.add('glitchAnimate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    plusSlides(1);
    gltch.classList.remove('glitchAnimate');
  }, 500);
}

function minusGlitch() {
  var gltch = document.getElementById('glitchArea');
  gltch.classList.add('glitchAnimate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    plusSlides(-1);
    gltch.classList.remove('glitchAnimate');
  }, 500);
}

function prettyGlitch() {
  var gltch = document.getElementById('glitchArea');
  gltch.classList.add('glitchAnimate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    gltch.classList.remove('glitchAnimate');
  }, 500);
}

// Fancy Particles //

particlesJS ("particleWeb", 
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 113,
      "density": {
        "enable": false,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#42C8F4"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.75,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.25,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 15,
        "size_min": 1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#78C043",
      "opacity": 0.6,
      "width": 1.2
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "bounce",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": false
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
} 
);
// it scales really really ugly, so: //

window.addEventListener('resize', particlesJS);

// SeerOfVoid and other URL appendices //

function htmlTag () {
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  if (urlParams.get("seerOfVoid") == "true") {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-seerOf", "void");
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', htmlTag);
```

```css
/* ----Body & Background---- */
html {
  --green: #78C043;
  --blue: #42C8F4;
  --purple: #AA6DA3;
  --grey: #544D56;
}
html:not([data-seerOf=void]) .void {
  display:none;
}

body {
  background: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: var(--green);
}

#backGrid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 2vw;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 96vw;
  background-image: url(http://fatcat-designs.com/images/green-grid2.svg);
  background-size: 40px;
  border-color: rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0.01rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.75) inset;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  z-index: -10;
}

#particleWeb { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
} 

/* ---Grid---- */
.grid-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5vh;
    left: 2.5vw;
    width: 95vw;
    height: 95vh;
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}

/* ----Logos---- */
#logo {
  /*width: 80%;*/
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
   grid-gap:10px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: min(100vw, 50vh);
}
#Farrago {
}
#deptLogo {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
   grid-gap:10px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: min(100vw, 50vh);
}
#NSCS {
}
/* ----Button ----*/
#enter {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
   grid-gap:10px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: min(100vw, 50vh);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* ----Specific Text Sections---- */
.void {
    color: var(--purple);
}

/* ----All Buttons---- */
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.5);
  border-color: var(--green);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5);
  color: var(--blue);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
}
button::selection {
  background: var(--blue); 
  color: #000000;
}
button::-moz-selection {
  background: var(--blue); 
  color: #000000;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0.25);
  border-color: var(--blue);
}
button:focus {
  color: var(--blue);
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--blue);
}
button:active {
  background: rgba(84, 77, 86, 0);
  color: var(--purple);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(120, 192, 67, 0.5) inset;
}

/* ----Specific Buttons---- */
.enter {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: min(3vw, 3vh);
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    max-height: 50%;
}

/* ----Glitch Transition Animations---- */
.glitchAnimate {
  --glitch-width: 100%;
    --glitch-height: 100%;
    --gap-horizontal: 10px;
    --gap-vertical: 5px;
    --time-anim: 2.5s;
    animation-name: glitch-anim-text;
    animation-duration: var(--time-anim);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: var(--glitch-width);
    height: var(--glitch-height);
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-text {
    0% { 
        transform: translate3d(calc(-1 * var(--gap-horizontal)),0,0) scale3d(-1,-1,1);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 20%, 100% 21%, 0 21%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 20%, 100% 21%, 0 21%);
    }
    2% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 33%, 100% 33%, 100% 33%, 0 33%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 33%, 100% 33%, 100% 33%, 0 33%);
    }
    4% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 44%, 100% 44%, 100% 44%, 0 44%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 44%, 100% 44%, 100% 44%, 0 44%);
    }
    5% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 20%, 0 20%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 20%, 0 20%);
    }
    6% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%, 100% 70%, 100% 70%, 0 70%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 70%, 100% 70%, 100% 70%, 0 70%);
    }
    7% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 100% 80%, 100% 80%, 0 80%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 100% 80%, 100% 80%, 0 80%);
    }
    8% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 55%, 0 55%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 55%, 0 55%);
    }
    9% {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%, 100% 70%, 100% 80%, 0 80%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 70%, 100% 70%, 100% 80%, 0 80%);
    }
    9.9% {
        transform: translate3d(calc(-1 * var(--gap-horizontal)),0,0) scale3d(-1,-1,1);
    }
    10%, 100% {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="backGrid">
  <div id="particleWeb"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container" id="glitchArea">
  <div id="logo">
      <img id="Farrago" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/FarragoFuture_Logo.png" alt="Farrago Fiction logo" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div id="deptLogo">
      <img id="NSCS" src="http://fatcat-designs.com/images/Narrative_Stability_Customer_Support_Centered.png" alt="Narrative Stability Customer Support" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div id="enter">
    <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="prettyGlitch(); location.href='/dead_messages/userSite.php';">User Site</button>
    <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="prettyGlitch(); location.href='/dead_messages/loginPage.php';">Employee Login</button>
  </div>
</div>    

<!-- particles.js lib - https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js --> 
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

You can also check [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/bGwJdPG)

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't _quite_ work, because it stopped the images from resizing correctly when the browser is strongly vertical (eg - for mobile).  This did push me in the right direction when continuing to look for a solution, tho.